# Binomial Expansion polynomial with remainder

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

Got his question:
(a) Use the binomial theorem to expand (x+1)^99, and show that (x+1)^99 = x^2f(x) + 99x + 1, where f(x) is a function in x.

(b) Using the result in (a), find the remainder when 7^99 is divided by 9.

The answer of (b) is 1. I got 1/9, why am I wrong?

Comment: Could you detail a bit more what you derived and did to obtain this $1/9$? This will help us figure out what could have gone wrong. Also, what definition do you have for "remainder"? Note that according to the standard definition, it *has* to be an integer.

Comment: AH...yes, integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+1)^{99}=\sum_{k=0}^{99}\binom{99}k\,x^k=1+\binom{99}1\,x+\binom{99}2x^2+\sum_{k=2}^{99}\binom{99}k\,x^k=$$

$$1+99x+x^2\left(\binom{99}2+\sum_{k=2}^{99}\binom{99}k\,x^{k-2}\right)$$

This proves (a), and as for (b):

$$7^{99}=(6+1)^{99}\stackrel{(a)}=1+99\cdot6+6^2f(6)=1\pmod 9$$

since $\;99\;$ and $\;6^2\;$ are divisible by $\;9\;$ .

Comment: Thanks for the detailed calculations, Joanpemo.

If I do not use mod 9,

7^99=(6+1)^99=1+99⋅6+62f(6)
What is the next step?

Comment: $$7^99 = 9\cdot\left(11\cdot 6 + 4\cdot f(6)\right)+1= 9q+1.$$ (You will need the fact that $f(6)$ is an integer to conclude, as you need $q$ to be an integer.)

Comment: @ClementC.Thank you. That, of course, is trivial and I think the asker can dedcue it by himself.

Comment: @user256670 Divide through by $\;9\;$ . It's the same, of course.

Comment: f(6) must be an integer because of the nature of Binomial Theorem, am I correct?

Comment: @user256670 Exactly. In fact, all you need is to know the binomial *coefficient* $\;\binom nk\;$ is an integer, since the rest in each summand is a power of the integer $\;6\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {10}9 = 1 + \frac 19$

Here the remainder is $1$ and not $\frac 19$

Just a matter of fact - Remainders can never be fractions. They have to be whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I have made a terrible mistake.